# How do I reverse proxy the homepage/root using nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm interested in sending folks who go to the root/homepage of my site to another server.

If they go anywhere else (/news or /contact or /hi.html or any of the dozens of other pages) they get proxied to a different server.

Since "/" is the nginx catchall to send anything that's not defined to a particular server, and since "/" also represents the homepage, you can see my predicament.

Essentially the root/homepage is its own server. Everything else is on a different server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location =/ {
    # only "/" requests
}

location / {
    # everything else
}
```

More information: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location